# RegEx for finding strings with chars and numbers

Tags: regex, string, regex-greedy

I am trying to match strings that are part numbers mixed with normal text.

Here are a few examples.

1. Towing Cntrl Ecu,Gl3t-19H378-Ac
2. Assy,Pwr,Tested Gd,Priv-M50t3
3. Left,Rear,Brn-Tan,Pwr,4DR,Mju1
4. T-Case Ecu,56029590AE
5. Right,Blind Spot Module,284K0 9HS0F

In these examples I am trying to match.

1. Gl3t-19H378-Ac
2. Priv-M50t3
3. Mju1
4. 56029590AE
5. 284K0 and 9HS0F

I am in .Net and this is the Regex I have been using.

```
(\b[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,32}(\b|$)(?<=[0-9]))
```

It works for what I need if the match ends in a number.  The rule I want is to match any string between word boundaries that is either all numbers or numbers and chars mixed, but never just chars.

Comment: Don't you want to also match `4DR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\d[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\b
```

If you need to restrict the length to a maximum of 32, add a look ahead:

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,32}\b)[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\d[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\b
```

If the underscore character is OK too, you can use `[\w-]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`.

Comment: `{,32}` might be parsed literally in some regex flavors, or as `{0,33}` in some other flavors. It makes sense to always specify the lower bound, `{0,32}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the pointer (I’ve never used .net). However, it would need to be `{1,32}` in this case.

Comment: Yes, and still it matches `4DR` that OP did not mention.